# Error in creating countdown timer in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, flash-cs5.5

I am trying to add timer in Flash CS5.5 with the code I've found. But it seems that there are few errors which I've corrected but still my output isnt works well. The error is access undefined property of txt.
 Can anyone help me to check it out? Thanks in advance!

```
GameOver.visible = false;

timerFunction(0, 12);

function timerFunction(minutes, seconds)

{
    var seconds = seconds;
    var minutes = minutes;
    var clock;
    var tmr = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer() {
        seconds--;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            minutes--;
            seconds = 59;
        }

        if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(tmr);
            GameOver.visible = true;
        }

        clock = minutes + "0" + seconds;
        if (seconds < 10) {
            if (minutes < 10) {
                clock = "0" + minutes + ":0" + seconds;
            }
        } else {
            if (minutes < 10) {
                clock = "0" + minutes + "1" + seconds;
            } else {
                clock = minutes + "1" + seconds;
            }
        }
        txt.embedFonts = false;
        txt.text = clock;
    }
}
```

Here is my zip file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/evm5alnbypty41y/Untitled-3.rar?dl=0

Comment: You need to add the relevant code and errors in the question. It's nice to have the .fla file and source to download to check it out but your question will be closed as off-topic if you don't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've edited my question. Thank you @xxbbcc

Comment: could you copy the relevant code into the question?

Comment: @Jezzamon I've copied the code into the question.

Comment: Your error is because `txt` apparently doesn't exist. (Are you sure at whatever frame this is running that there is something with the instance name of `txt` and that it's in this context and continues to exist so long as your interval is running?)   As an aside, you should use an actual `Timer` object instead of setInterval. It's much easier to work with. Also, avoid the inline functions as they usually result in memory leaks and other unexpected things

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis thank you for your help. Now i can see my mistake. But, what do you mean by inline function? I tried to change to Timer object instead of setInterval, but an error appeared "Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 11 1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 1."

Comment: I can't tell you the problem without seeing the code.  Update your question.  Inline functions are functions within functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a text to the stage and name it "txt"

or

Do it programatically by adding these lines at the begining of your lines

```
 import flash.text.TextField;

 var txt:TextField = new TextField ;
 txt.embedFonts = true ;
 addChild(txt);
```

Use the following code (it's tested)

```
           import flash.utils.Timer;
           import flash.events.TimerEvent;

      var seconds:int ;
      var minutes:int ;
      var totalTimeInSeconds:int 
      var ticker:int ;


 var tmr:Timer ;

 function timerFunction(minutes, seconds)

 {
  totalTimeInSeconds = minutes * 60 + seconds
tmr = new Timer (1000,totalTimeInSeconds);
tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerClick);
tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,timerComplete) ;
tmr.start() ;

}

 timerFunction(2, 15)
 function timerClick (e:TimerEvent):void
 {
 var curMinute:int = Math.floor((totalTimeInSeconds - ticker)/60) ;
 var curSecond:int =  (totalTimeInSeconds - ticker) -  (curMinute*60)  ;
 txt.text =  curMinute + ":" + curSecond;
 ticker +=1 ;
 }

 function timerComplete (E:TimerEvent):void
 {  
   txt.text = "0:0" ;
   tmr.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerClick);
   tmr.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,timerComplete) ;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is settled. But I still cant make the timer works properly.

Comment: 1- Make textfield on stage and name it "txt" (make sure to embed the font) and use my code

Comment: I've tried your code. No errors appear but the score doesnt appear. Do you know why?

Comment: I've tried your code. No errors appear but the score doesnt appear. Do you know why?

Comment: I guess you should add    ( GameOver.visible = true; )
at  timerComplete()  function ,  just before the line ( txt.text = "0:0" ;)

Comment: the countdown timer were gone after a sec. While the score remains invisible.

Comment: I've downloaded your project it works just as expected . you can download it set the "00:00" text name int "txt" remove your code  then past my code just under  "GameOver.visible = false; " , and don't forget to add "GameOver.visible = true; " as I told you